# Wordpress directory function adds dot to URL

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have done the following In my code:

```
/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function design_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }

    wp_enqueue_script( 'navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/navigation.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20120206', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'design_scripts' );
```

But somehow the function adds a dot to the url like this:

```
http://domain/wp-content/themes/design/./style.css
```

Anybody knows why? Havent been able to figure it out yet myself.

Comment: what happens if you echo get_template_directory_uri()   ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url') );
```

On a side note, you don't need to enqueue your theme's normal Stylesheet if this is a theme you're building. Adding it directly in your header is fine.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
```

Comment: get_bloginfo results in the same url http://domain/wp-content/themes/design/./style.css also I thought that enqueueing was better.

Comment: Enqueuing is better for scripts and stylesheets that are not native to the Wordpress framework or naming conventions. Out of morbid curiosity, what happens when you use the second approach?

Comment: When I do the second approach with an added echo :p I get <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://domain/wp-content/themes/design/./style.css" />

Comment: I'll be honest: I'm pretty stumped. My only other suggestion would be to check your wp_options table and take a look at the options named 'stylesheet' and 'template' (option_id of 45 and 46 respectively in my own table, it might be different for you). If there's a trailing '/./' at the end of either of them, remove it.

Comment: I checked the Database and there was design/. as value just dont know why :s fixed now ;)